# Adding a ToolStripDropDownMenu to MenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip

I am working on a winforms application in C# using VS.

I know I can add a `ToolStripMenuItem` to a `MenuStrip` in the designer like so:

```
this.mnuFile = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem(); 
this.MainMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip();   
this.MainMenu1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.mnuFile,
            });
```

I know I can't simply add it to `AddRange` because they are different types. Is it possible to add a `ToolStripDropDownMenu` to a `MenuStrip` in some other way?

```
this.mnuEdit = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownMenu();
```

Comment: @HansPassant How come i get a Cannot convert type ToolStripDropDownMenu to ToolStripItem error then?

Comment: ToolStripDropDownMenu does not inherit from ToolStripItem, it inherits from ToolStripDropDown, which inherits from ToolStrip.  You can try a ToolStripDropDownButton.  Not sure what your end goal is though.

Comment: Oops, it derives from ToolStrip.  Hmm, putting a menu in a menu item ought to end poorly.  You can try it anyway with a ToolStripControlHost.

Comment: @LarsTech ToolStripItem doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @HansPassant Putting a menu in a menu item does sound silly now that you mention it. I'm playing around with using ToolStripMenuItem in the end, i'll update if i find a solution